# Python array returns different value

Tags: python, arrays, list, scope, stack

[Original Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hfmzx.png)

I was working on a coding problem of finding all permutations of a string. However, to my surprise, the codes on the left does not returns the result properly, so i did some debugging and found that the 'out' array was set to a empty list every time after a call stack. However, if i change the code and move the entire portion from the helper function to the main function as the right side of the code, the code works properly.

What causing the issue here?

Wrong output:

def answer(st):

```
out = []
if not st:
    out.append(" ")
    return out 

head = st[0]        
last = answer(st[1:]) 
for perm in last:
    temp = helper(perm,head)
    out.append(temp)

return out
```

def helper(perm,head):

```
for x in range (len(perm)):
    stt = perm[:x] 
    stt+= head
    stt+= perm[x:]
    return stt
```

st = '12'
`

---

Correct output:
def answer(st):

```
out = []
if not st:
    out.append(" ")
    return out 

head = st[0]        
last = answer(st[1:]) 
for perm in last:
    for x in range (len(perm)):
        stt = perm[:x] 
        stt+= head
        stt+= perm[x:]
        out.append(stt)
    
return out
```

st = '12'

Comment: Please post your code using code snippets

Comment: Your code at left side does not cycle, it returns at 1st iteration and never goes further. Either use generator and yield all values or return array and extend instead of appending

Comment: but why is it that it only returns at the 1st iteration? The two sides looks almost identical to me.

Comment: It only returns at 1st iteration because your function returns at 1st iteration (watch how `return sst` stops for loop and ends the function)

Comment: omg, im so stupid and blind ! Thanks so much for your help! I was pulling my hair for hours on this one!